# Accessing an object variable from a generic type in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am a first year student learning OOP through Java.
I am trying to understand generic types and in the following example I am under the impression that disguisedAs() returns the pointer to the object instance. This is not the case.
Why isn't my code working and how can I get it to compile and run?
Thanks in advance!

```
public class GenericTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal tux = new Penguin();
        DisguisedPerson<Animal> dave = new DisguisedPerson<Animal>(tux, "Dave");
        dave.disguisedAs().call();
        dave.reveal();
    }
}
interface Disguised <T> {
    T disguisedAs();
}
class Person {
    String name;

    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}  
class DisguisedPerson<U> extends Person implements Disguised<U> {
    U resembles;
    DisguisedPerson(U costume, String name) {
        super(name);
        resembles = costume;
    }

    public U disguisedAs() {
        return resembles;
    }

    void reveal() {
        System.out.println(name + " was dressed up as a " + disguisedAs().species); // returns error: cannot find symbol!
    }
}
abstract class Animal {
    String species;
    String call;

    Animal(String c) {
        species = this.getClass().getName();
        this.call = c;
    }
    void call() {
        System.out.println(this.call + "! ImA " + this.species);
    }
}
class Penguin extends Animal {
    Penguin() {
        super("Pip");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a real - specific question with a real code after you have already tried something. Too many users are trying the "give me the code" questions lately :\

Answer (score 2):

Your call does work because `U` can be any type.

If you make U extends Animal, then you can use fields/methods of an Animal.

```
class DisguisedPerson<U extends Animal>
```

You have to do this or you could write

```
DisguisedPerson<Integer> dave = new DisguisedPerson<Integer>(1, "One");
```

Comment: Yes! (My feelings would be more precisely expressed if I followed that up with 23 exclamations and then some)  
Thank you so much for making this key-point obvious to me! Now I am ready to do my assignment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The generic class `DisguisedPerson<U>` does not know the specific generic type, and specifically, it doesn't know `disguisedAs()` returns an `Animal`, it returns a `U`, but you do not know what this `U` is, it could be an `Object`, and obviously `Object` does not have a field `species`.

Remember that the actual object, which is indeed in your case an `Animal` is "known" only in run time, and since java there is [static typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing), it needs to "know" the actual type at compile time, so it assumes a `Object`, unless you specify `U extends ....` [in your case `U extends Animal`].

Comment: Thank you for making that perfectly clear to me. It was helpful to have the ambiguity of my syntax pointed out clearly so I have a full understanding of the problem.

Comment: @jollyroger: You are most welcome, and good luck with your assigment!